# Jest/Enzyme | Test a function call in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, es6-promise, enzyme

What to do when you want to test that a function is been called, on `componentDidMount()` React lifecycle Method. Basically the component code looks like this:

```
  state = {
    randomStateToPopulate: []
  };

  // Test componentDidMount
  componentDidMount() {
    this.randomFunction();
  }

  randomFunction= () => {
    listRandomData().then(({ data }) => {
      this.setState({ randomStateToPopulate: data });
    });
  };
```

So, how to you actually test this case?

Comment: As written, the only way to test this component appears to be "white box", which means you'd write an assertion based on the state of `randomFunction` (whether it has been called, for example) or `randomStateToPopulate` (whether it was assigned to `data`). But white box testing has the drawback that if you change your internal implementation, the test can break. If you show how you're _using_  `randomStateToPopulate` (putting it into an HTML list, for example), you can write a test that isn't bound to implementation details.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is the case scenario you want to test. If the componentDidMount is being called, check that it has been called only once, or as many times you want.

Your test. `I have the explanation in comments below`

```
    // Inside your general `Describe`
  let wrapper;
  const props = {
    // Your props goes here..
  };
  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallow(<YourComponent {...props} />);
  });

    it('should check `componentDidMount()`', () => {
      const instance = wrapper.instance(); // you assign your instance of the wrapper
      jest.spyOn(instance, 'randomFunction'); // You spy on the randomFunction
      instance.componentDidMount();
      expect(instance.randomFunction).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1); // You check if the condition you want to match is correct.
    });
```

You can abstract, this case to do more complex things, but the basic gist of it is the above one. If you have a more detailed or better solution, please post it. Thanks!!

Comment: this is correct. you must invoke componentDidMount() yourself in the test case.

Comment: in my case `instance` is `null`, regardless if I use `mount` or `shallow` :(

Comment: @GregWoz I was getting the same result as you. For me, it looked like I had a ReactFragment as the parent html tag that my component was returning. something like: "return (<><MyComponent/></>)" and that was messing everything up. I fixed that by using Find on the instance (instance.Find('MyComponent'))