# How to test that a react component renders both its states correctly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Before rendering all the UI elements I check that the relevant state parameters aren't null.

```
render() {
        if(this.state.one === null 
            || this.state.two === null 
            || this.state.three === null){
            return <div/>
        }
        return(
            // divs for actual UI 
        )
}
```

Then in my test I check that component matches the snapshot, the initial state has null parameters, so the snapshot will only return the one empty div. So, that works, I can check that the component isn't rendered when it shouldn't be, but how can I add another snapshot, or something else, to see that everything is rendered correctly when the state no longer contains null?

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import TheUIComponent from './TheUIClass';

let component;

beforeEach(() => {
    component = shallow(<TheUIComponent/>);
});

describe('UIComponent', () => {
    it('should render correctly', () => {
        expect(component).toMatchSnapshot();
        
    });
}
```

Comment: What has to happen in your component for the state to become non-null? User interaction is unlikely, so you're loading the state from an API maybe?

Comment: Those states are updated via mqtt subscriptions. In the class I use `componentDidMount()` in which I have three separate subscriptions that update the three different `this.state._`.

Comment: Then mock the mqtt subscription functions and [call componentDidMount manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54942893/3083470) - I haven't ever tested class based components myself, but you probably have to rerender manually with `component.render()` and can then assert on the output. If you just want to test the render based on state, you can probably just set the state from outside and rerender manually.

Comment: I can set the states manually, and rerender manually, but I don't quite understand how to test that the render is correct. I could spy on render and see if it has been called but how can I see that the correct content has been rendered as I do with the snapshot for the first empty case?

Comment: Shouldn't you be able to do `expect(component.render()).toMatchSnapshot()` after setting the state?

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work. I was under the impression that having two snapshots in the same test would overwrite each other and always make one of them fail. Maybe I had some syntax wrong when I first tested this out.